# :target css pseudoclass doesn't work properly in Firefox when it's set on content inside iframe

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-class

I've created two simple html pages, one of which contains iframe and second one is loaded into that iframe of first page.
First page is located at http://quatorze.atspace.co.uk/Webdev/shared/ffbug1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>:target bug in firefox</title>
    <style type=text/css>
    iframe:target {
        display: none;
    }
    ol {
        max-width: 480px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    li {
        margin: 8px;
    }
    span {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div0">
        <p><a href="#if">HIDE</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#div0">SHOW</a></p>
        <iframe id="if" src="ffbug_files/ffbug3.html" width="400" height="200"></iframe>
        <ol>In Firefox click links on this page in following order:
            <li>Click "DIV 1". First div gets targeted and its background turns silver;</li>
            <li>Click "HIDE". Iframe gets targeted and its "display" property is set to "none";</li>
            <li>Click "SHOW". Iframe is no longer targeted and its "display" property is reset to "inline";</li>
            <li>Now click "DIV 2". Second div gets targeted and its background turns silver. First div is no longer targeted and its "background-color" must be reset to "skyblue" but <span>it remains silver</span>;</li>
            <li>Click "DIV 1". First div gets targeted, its background <span>was already silver</span>, second div is no longer targeted and its "background-color" is reset to "skyblue".</li>
            <li>Click "DIV 2". Second div gets targeted, its background turns silver, first div is no longer targeted, its "background-color"  is reset to "skyblue".</li>
            <li>Click "HIDE". Iframe gets targeted and its "display" property is set to "none";</li>
            <li>Click "SHOW". Iframe is no longer targeted and its "display" property is reset to "inline";</li>
            <li>Now click "DIV 1". First div gets targeted, its background turns silver. Second div is no longer targeted and its "background-color" must be reset to "skyblue", but <span>it remains silver</span>.
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second page that is loaded in iframe is located at http://quatorze.atspace.co.uk/Webdev/shared/ffbug_files/ffbug3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>:target bug in firefox</title>
    <style type=text/css>
    div {
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
        border: 2px solid;
        margin: 6px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: skyblue;
        float: left;
    }
    div:target {
        background-color: silver;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"><a href="#div1">DIV 1</a></div>
    <div id="div2"><a href="#div2">DIV 2</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see there are two links on first page named "SHOW" and "HIDE".

"SHOW" reffers to containing div, and "HIDE" reffers to iframe.

Iframe's "display" property is set to "none" when it gets targeted.

Second page, that is loaded in iframe contains two divs. Each div has a link inside it that refers to that div.

CSS rule set on each div makes it change its background color when it gets targeted from "skyblue" to "silver".

In Firefox try to click the links on first page in following order:

1. Click "DIV 1". First div gets targeted and its background turns
   silver;
2. Click "HIDE". Iframe gets targeted and its "display" property is set
   to "none";
3. Click "SHOW". Iframe is no longer targeted and its "display"
   property is reset to "inline";
4. Now click "DIV 2". Second div gets targeted and its background turns
   silver. First div is no longer targeted and its "background-color"
   must be reset to "skyblue" (that's what actually happens in Chrome),
   but it remains silver.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me mate. I am using FireFox 24.

Comment: My Operating System is Windows XP SP3, maybe it doesn't work on XP. I don't know what else to think.

Comment: No, I don't think Operating System should be an issue here. What version of FireFox are you using? Try upgrading to the latest.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 24 it's the latest version. Are you sure you clicked the links in exactly same order as specified?

Comment: I disabled all my plug-ins and extensions but it didn't help either :(

Comment: I can reproduce the issue! FF23 Win7

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=919297 please leave your comment there. Thanks.

Comment: Also reproduced on Win7 FF21 and reproduced correct behavior on Win7 Chrome30 and IE9. Also confirm that iFrame page works correctly in FF when viewed as stand alone page.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the answer you are seeking, but it's a practical one.

If you are trying to accomplish cross-browser compatibility for your project, then you should be seeking that subset of functionality each browser does well, and use that.

Since you appear to have applied the styles properly, if you get correct functionality in one browser and not another, you simply need to apply your energy to finding a common approach that works in both.

Even if Firefox would fix this bug for you, you would still have visitors running into it for a good while to come.

Answer (score -1):

You should try jquery, I believe it will do well. I run in chrome in your code, no problem. Appears you said the problem in firefox, you can click on it will show div1, div2 reset to blue. You try, I hope you can help .